# CastError when posting to edit route

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to edit a note using mongoose these are my get/post routes

```
app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
res.render("index", {date: date});
});

app.get("/register", (req, res) => {
res.render("register", {date: date});
});

app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
res.render("login", {date: date});
});

app.get("/main", ensureAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    const foundUserNotes = await User.find({"notes": {$ne: null}}).exec();
    if (foundUserNotes[0].notes) {
        res.render("main", {date: date, notes: foundUserNotes[0].notes})
    }
} else {
    res.redirect("/login");
} 
});

app.get("/note", (req, res) => {
if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    res.render("note", {date: date});
} else {
    res.redirect("/login");
}
});

app.get("/edit", async (req, res) => {
if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    const userId = req.session.userId;
    const foundUserNotes = await User.find({_id: userId})
    console.log(foundUserNotes[0].notes);
    res.render("edit", {date: date, notes: foundUserNotes[0].notes});
} else {
    res.redirect("/login");
}
});

app.get("/logout", (req, res) => {
req.logout(function(err) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    res.redirect('/');
  });
});

app.post("/note", async (req, res) => {
const userId = req.session.userId;  
const foundUser = await User.findById(userId).exec();
if (foundUser) {
    const note = new Note({
        noteBody: req.body.noteBody,
        userId: foundUser._id
    });     
    foundUser.notes.push(note);
    foundUser.save();
    res.redirect("/main");
}  
});



app.post("/delete", async (req, res) => {
const userId = req.session.userId;
const itemId = req.body.itemId;
await User.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, 
{
    $pull: {
        "notes": {_id: itemId}
    }
});
res.redirect("/main");
});

app.post("/edit", async (req, res) => {
const userId = req.session.userId;
const itemId = req.body.itemId;
await User.findByIdAndUpdate(userId , 
    {
        $pull: {"notes": {_id: itemId}}
    });
res.redirect("/main");
});

app.post("/register", (req, res) => {
User.register({username: req.body.username}, req.body.password, function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.redirect("/register");
    } else {
        passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function() {
            res.redirect("/main");
        });
    }
});
});

app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
const user = new User ({
    username: req.body.username,
    password: req.body.password,
});
req.login(user, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        passport.authenticate("local") (req, res, function() {
            res.redirect("/main");
        });
    }
});
});
```

I get the following error:
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "" (type string) at path "_id" because of "BSONError"

When I comment out the app.post("/edit") the error disappears but the edit function does not work.
While looking at other questions here the problem seemed to be the order of the get/post routes but after trying to re-arrange mine the error persisted.
How do I go about troubleshooting this error? I don't know where to start.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Inside your `app.post("/edit"` can you do a `console.log('userId =',  req.session.userId);` then `console.log('itemId =', req.body.itemId);` as the first two statements in the function. One of them is empty. Once you know which one, you will be able to debug.

Comment: Once again coming to my recuse. Thank you. One single typo was my problem.

Comment: You're welcome.